# Trying to return a range as function output, get type mismatch?

Tags: excel, vba

The following function returns a "type mismatch". I don't understand, as I paid attention to using the "Set" instruction to return my resulting range.

I debugged the function, I get a proper range to return, so the problem is elsewhere.. Hmmmm...

```
Function getVals(column As String) As Range
    Dim col As Variant
    col = Application.Match(column, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("1:1"), 0)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col)
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
    Set getVals = rng
End Function
```

Thanks in advance guys for any help :)

UPDATE : I am looking at how to send my results as an array. I tried combinations of the function returning "variant"/"variant()" type, and passing rng.value2 as result, but no success.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use `column` as a variable name given `Column` is part of the Excel object model

Comment: With several people trying to find your problem without success, I think it is try for you to give more information.  For example:  (1) Which statement is giving a type mismatch?  (2) What does row 1 contain?

Comment: Row 1 contains column headers. I look them up, and the objective is to return the values under the matched header.

Comment: The type mismatch happens at runtime, on the last statement, even when my rng range is set to the expected range... I don't get it.

Comment: In that case, maybe the problem is actually not in this formula but where you are using it. How are you calling it? I've tried testing your code several ways and the only time I get a type mismatch error is if I pass in an invalid column string.

Comment: I just try to call it from the Immediate Window, with an actual column string that appears on the sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return your results as an array of values, simply change the return type to `Variant` and return `rng.Value`. The below code works for me as long as the passed `column` string exists in `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("1:1")`.

```
Function getVals(column As String) As Variant
    Dim col As Variant
    col = Application.Match(column, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("1:1"), 0)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col)
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
    getVals = rng.Value
End Function

Sub TestingGetVals()
   Dim v As Variant, i As Integer
   v = getVals("a")  ' returns a 2-D array
   For i = 1 To UBound(v)
      Debug.Print v(i, 1)
   Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because Match is not able to find what you want and hence your rng is evaluating to "nothing" :)

Consider this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
     Dim Ret As Range

     If Not getVals("Value To Match") Is Nothing Then
        Set Ret = getVals("Value To Match")
        MsgBox Ret.Address
     Else
        MsgBox "Value To Match - Not Found"
     End If
End Sub

Function getVals(column As String) As Range
    Dim col As Variant
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    col = Application.Match(column, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("1:1"), 0)

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col)

    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
    Set getVals = rng

    Exit Function
Whoa:
    Set getVals = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my tests, Match is returning what I want. I do a "select" right before the return and my range corresponds to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just tested once more, same trouble as I have (our sources are virtually identical)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I do not understand what you are doing.  You have a parameter `column` but you are searching for a cell within row 1 that contains that value.  For example, if column = 23, and P1 contains 23, Match should return 16.

Your routine fails because if the Match fails, col is set to `Error 2042`.  You should test col before using it as a number.

In my test I set row 1 to numbers in a random sequence.  My Match failed because cell P1 contained number 23 but variable column contains string "23".  When I reclassified column as Long, the Match worked.

I am unhappy with Siddharth's use of `On Error`.  I do not like to use `On Error` for errors I expect.  I would test col to be numeric after the Match.

Comment: One always has an option to add more code in error handling. If you know what errors you might face, might as well trap it as you rightly mentioned. The above is just an example if the match is not found :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout. My remark sounds more critical than I intended. I have since noticed you normally include `On Error`. I approve, we should plan for the unexpected. My only criticism, you do not explain why. While we have the OP's attention I believe we should give more background, context and advice than they strictly need because this will help them develop and grow. I learnt at an early age the cost of not checking for errors.  Perhaps I over do it but my obsessive error checking does help isolate the cause of problems. This is a lesson I try to pass on the next generation.

Comment: I agree with your point of view :) Will try and include more comments in the code next time. Thanks for the constructive criticism :)

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's not the cause of my issue. Column is a string, so the behavior you described in the first place is the one aimed for. I'm aware of my not handling Error 2042, but the issue is else here.

Answer (score 0):

Other people are faster at writing then I am.  :-)  There is one other possibility that hasn't been mentioned yet.

Since you didn't get the error when debugging, the issue might be your use of `ActiveSheet`.  If the wrong worksheet is active then Match will cause the error as stated by the other answers.

If you are explicit, does the error go away?

```
col = Application.Match(column, ThisWorkbook.Sheet(1).Range("1:1"), 0)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think that has nothing to do with my issue.